# From where to start Tlauncher to play minecraft after installation?

Tags: icons, games, minecraft

I have installed Tlauncher by downloading its setup from its official website. After installation, I downloaded minecraft game inside it and started playing the game. and then I quit the game and the Tlauncher.

Now I can not find any Tlauncher icon nor minecraft icon.
tell me from where to start the Tlauncher and play minecraft game again.
plzz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to launch it from the .jar file you downloaded. It never actually installs the Tlauncher, it just runs from java.

Comment: The first time I ran it, I did it through the CLI. Wasn't able to figure out how to launch it without it until I went to the .jar file's permissions and enabled it to be run as an .exe. Now it launches on double-clicking. I was forced to re-download the game once I launched it this way, but that happens just once. I believe that you'll be asked to re-download the game each time if you go through the CLI.

Answer (score -1):

Run the TLauncher file as root, And it will load your installed game:

```
sudo java -jar TLauncher.jar
```

It can also be run in User mode just make a new launcher and add:

```
java -jar /path/to/TLauncher.jar
```

Comment: Running any game as root is a Bad Idea™

Comment: Especially if it's done using a shady cracked launcher. You're just asking for malware.